# How to limit "Windows ProbIem Steps recorder" to a single monitor?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, problem-step-recorder

The Problem Steps Recorder (psr.exe) in Windows 7 and newer is a great tool to quickly record something on youe system. It takes screen shots of whatever you are doing. But I have four monitors and the screenshot is always for all four, while what I want to record is happening on a single display only.

I'm trying to limit the recorder to a single screen without luck.

The command line switches for Windows 7 are:

```
 /start         :Start Recording. (Outputpath flag SHOULD be specified)
 /stop          :Stop Recording.
 /sc            :Capture screenshots for recorded steps.
 /maxsc         :Maximum number of recent screen captures.
 /maxlogsize    :Maximum log file size (in MB) before wrapping occurs.
 /gui           :Display control GUI.
 /arcetl        :Include raw ETW file in archive output.
 /arcxml        :Include MHT file in archive output.
 /recordpid     :Record all actions associated with given PID.
 /sketch        :Sketch UI if no screenshot was saved.
 /slides        :Create slide show HTML pages.
 /output        :Store output of record session in given path.
 /stopevent     :Event to signal after output files are generated.
```

I know the Windows 8.1 version has at least two more:

```
 /multiok
 /hadsettings
```

they both take integers values as parameters but I can't find any information on how to use them and whether they are helpful for single display capture.

Answer (score 3):

The last answer in the following post is the simplest solution, to go to single-monitor mode: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/problem-steps-recorder-editing-trimming-the-screen/bbee545d-370e-407e-baa8-42ebbb7908db?auth=1.

The text of that answer follows:

> In a two monitor setup and when you want PSR to only capture one monitor, this is easily resolved by temporarily disabling your second monitor. To do this, go to Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display\Screen Resolution, and in the 'Multiple displays' drop-down, select 'Show desktop only on 1'.

An alternative solution was also posted in the thread:

> If you have Microsoft Office Word 2007 installed, you can open the xxx.mht file in that program.
>   Select the image you wish to edit, click the Format Tab and use the Crop tool.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to turn off the monitor you do not want to record, then only the monitor(s) that are on will be recorded.

Comment: Actually this probably doesn't deserve the downvote, in some cases it would work (In others it wouldn't) depending on if windows decides to reconfigure the monitors or not.  The better answer is to disable it since shutting one down probably doesn't give reliable results.